# uploading bytes to server via outputstream

Tags: java, android, upload, network-programming

I am trying to  upload some bytes to the server for 15 seconds.I have written the following code to write the bytes to output stream :

```
        long uploadedBytes=0;
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream=null;
        OutputStream outputStream=null;
        try {
            byte[] randomData=generateBinData(5*1024);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) 1024 * 5];
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = 
                    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();

            byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(randomData);
            long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            while(byteArrayInputStream.read(bytes) > 0 
                    && timeDiff < 15000) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                uploadedBytes += bytes.length;
                byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(randomData);
                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                int progress=(int)(timeDiff *100 / 15000);
                publishProgress(progress);
            }
```

But the progress for the above upload is running very fast and it shows large amount of bytes uploaded within seconds.Which is not according to my 2g mobile network connection.
For example it shows : 
             uploadedBytes =9850880 and with time difference(timeDiff) = 3 sec.

if i run the same code for 15 seconds it terminates the whole application.
Please help me to find where i am goind wrong.
thanks ...waiting for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you set chunked or streaming transfer mode, `HttpURLConnection` buffers all the output before sending any of it, so it can get a Content-Length. So what you're seeing is the progress of the buffering, not of the transfer. Set chunked transfer mode and you will see a difference.

Your copy loop is wrong. It should be like this:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Your code will probably work in this specific case but that's not a reason not to get it right for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

check your random byte length. i think the generateBinData() method is not generating 5Kb of data.

sure the uploadedBytes is huge. say, if a write to outputstream takes 10 milisec to write 5Kb(5*1024) of data,in 3 second you should able to write only 153600 bytes.

Reason for app termination - check if any read operation throws exception.